# Como posso otimizar um método recursivo para encontrar ancestrais?

Tags: java, recursão, otimização

Eu tenho uma classe `Pessoa` que possuí relacionamentos para seu pai e sua mãe (esses a qualquer momento podem ser nulos).

Em determinado pedaço do meu código eu preciso descobrir se uma pessoa é ancestral da outra.

Consegui chegar à uma solução recursiva mais ou menos da seguinte natureza:

```java
public boolean isAncestor(Person p) {
    if (p == null)
        return false;
    if (this.father.equals(p) || this.mother.equals(p))
        return true;
    else if(isAncestor(p.father) || isAncestor(p.mother))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

O problema é que essas árvores genealógicas podem se tornar razoavelmente grandes. Além do que essa implementação está parecendo muito com a implementação recursiva trivial de Fibonacci... Ou seja pode ser impressão minha, mas acredito que esse seja um método de natureza `O(2^n)`.

Vocês conseguem pensar em uma maneira mais eficiente de checar por ancestrais? Quem sabe não exista alguma solução com loops + pilhas ou uma recursão não exponencial para resolver o problema?

Comment: Na sequência de Fibonacci existem muitos elementos que se repetem (ex.: `X` e `X-1` ambos usam `X-2` em seu cálculo), o que permite um cálculo em tempo linear. Não é o caso em uma árvore genealógica, em que o conjunto de ancestrais pode ter pouca ou nenhuma repetição.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema não é exponencial, é linear, mas é linear no número de ancestrais da pessoa: não tem como garantir que João não é ancestral de Maria sem examinar todos ancestrais de Maria.

Dá até para reduzir isso um pouco, eliminando ancestrais já examinados (uma mesma pessoa pode aparecer mais de uma vez como ancestral -- casamento entre primos, por exemplo), à custa de espaço linear no número de antepassados.

O mais fácil é usar uma fila para resolver isso:

```java
import java.util.*;

public boolean isAncestor(Person p) {
  if (p == null) return false;

  final Queue<Person> notChecked = new LinkedList<Person>();
  final Set<Person> checked = new HashSet<Person>();

  if (father != null) notChecked.add(father);
  if (mother != null) notChecked.add(mother);

  while (notChecked.peek() != null) {
    final Person nextPerson = notChecked.remove();

    if (!checked.contains(nextPerson)) {
      if (nextPerson == p) return true;

      checked.add(nextPerson);
      if (nextPerson.father != null) notChecked.add(nextPerson.father);
      if (nextPerson.mother != null) notChecked.add(nextPerson.mother);
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Outra possibilidade é usar uma pilha, baseada em `ArrayList`. A classe `ArrayList` é muito mais eficiente que a `LinkedList` em termos de espaço e velocidade, mas a implementação fica ligeiramente mais complicada:

```java
public boolean isAncestor(Person p) {
  if (p == null) return false;

  final List<Person> notChecked = new ArrayList<Person>();
  final Set<Person> checked = new HashSet<Person>();

  if (father != null) notChecked.add(father);
  if (mother != null) notChecked.add(mother);

  while (notChecked.size() > 0) {
    final int index = notChecked.size() - 1;
    final Person nextPerson = notChecked.remove(index);

    if (!checked.contains(nextPerson)) {
      if (nextPerson == p) return true;

      checked.add(nextPerson);
      if (nextPerson.father != null) notChecked.add(nextPerson.father);
      if (nextPerson.mother != null) notChecked.add(nextPerson.mother);
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Praticamente igual, mas muito mais rápida.

A primeira versão vai achar mais rapidamente ancestrais próximos -- a segunda versão, por exemplo, vai procurar todos os ancestrais da mãe antes de procurar o pai. As duas versões consomem o mesmo esforço caso a pessoa não seja ancestral, sendo que a segunda vai ser bem mais rápida e consumir menos memória.

Comment: Opa Sobral, muitíssimo obrigado. Ambas as versões estão mais rápidas do que a minha (usando micro-benchmarks). Infelizmente eu não tenho as árvores gigantescas de produção para testes. Você diria que no caso médio a segunda versão tende a ser mais rápida do que a primeira?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Imagino que a segunda versão é mais rápida, mas ela prioriza ancestrais maternos ou paternos, enquanto a primeira versão prioriza ancestrais próximos. Se parentese próximos forem muito mais comuns, ela pode se tornar mais rápida. Se "falso" (não é ancestral) for mais comum, a segunda é muito melhor.

Answer (score 5):

Dificilmente você irá encontrar uma solução eficiente, pois o número de candidatos nesse caso cresce exponencialmente a cada geração (i.e. uma pessoa tem 2 pais, 4 avós, 8 bisavós etc). A busca inversa (começar com o ancestral e procurar por seus filhos) potencialmente será ainda mais custosa, pois uma pessoa pode ter mais de 2 filhos. O uso de programação dinâmica pode amortizar um pouco nesse caso (ex.: se uma pessoa tem um mesmo ancestral tanto por parte de pai quanto de mãe), mas dependendo da configuração do seu conjunto de dados isso pode ou não fazer alguma diferença significativa.

Você pode eliminar a recursão usando uma pilha explícita, mas ainda assim esta crescerá tanto quanto a pilha implícita criada por sua solução recursiva. Portanto, a menos que você esteja enfrentando problemas de exaustão de memória, não há razão para se mudar a sua estratégia atual (busca em profundidade através da recursão).

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira de contornar esse problema é usar programação dinâmica (ou memoização).

A idéia é criar uma espécia de "cache" do resultado da função, pra você não ter que consultar de novo toda a hierarquia caso já tenha resolvido o problema para o objeto. Você pode fazer isso criando um atributo `HashMap` na classe e consultando no início do método.

```java
private Map<Person, Person> memoAncestors = new HashMap<Person, Person>();

// ....

public boolean isAncestor(Person p) {
    if (p == null)
        return false;
    if (memoAncestors.containsKey(p)) {
        return memoAncestors.get(p);
    }
    if (this.father.equals(p) || this.mother.equals(p)) {
        memoAncestors.put(p, true);
        return true;
    } else if(isAncestor(p.father) || isAncestor(p.mother)) {
        memoAncestors.put(p, true);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Essa solução é um tanto mais eficiente, pois evitará várias "subidas" na árvore desnecessárias e não prejudica muito a legibilidade o código -- um bom *tradeoff*. É também uma otimização conhecida para o problema de Fibonacci, se encaixa no que você está chamando de *recursão não exponencial*.

Comment: Eu estava lendo um pouco sobre [Memoização](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) e acho que não custa nada tentar. Acredito que possa uma serviço de cache distribuído ao estilo Memcached para evitar que esse cache cresça sem restrições (além de obter um nível de otimização maior do que um cache local uma vez que várias pessoas da mesma família podem usar a aplicação).

Comment: Por outro lado acredito que o @mgibsonbr tenha razão no sentido que, essa otimização deve reduzir o tempo de duas chamadas subsequentes ao método usando a mesma pessoa ou pessoas da mesma família, porém não é tão eficiente nesse caso quanto no caso do  Fibonacci que possuí [overlapping subproblems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems) (não sei como traduzir isso).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly É, vai depender da quantidade e tamanho dos dados que você terá. Tente deixar genérico, comece com uma implementação em memória. Apesar de não ter intrinsicamente subproblemas sobrepostos, você provavelmente vai pesquisar mais de uma vez a mesma pessoa -- basta existir um irmão numa família do meio da árvore, que você já economiza várias subidas.

Answer (score 2):

Este é um problema clássico de grafos, e você pode usar algumas técnicas para isso, dependendo do tamanho do problema que você tem. Caso seu problema seja em apenas alguns níveis, então calcular a árvore inteira talvez não tenha problema e sua solução é boa.

Novamente, seria melhor dar uma olhada nos algoritmos relacionados a grafos para ver qual seria o melhor para sua situação, mas vamos supor que você tenha milhares de famílias sem conexão umas com as outras. Para esta situação, vale a pena fazer uma união das famílias em um data set via "tree flatenning" (não sei o termo em português), e checar se os dois objetos estão no mesmo set. Como essa é uma operação rápida, você pode descartar rapidamente pessoas que não são da mesma família e, portanto, uma não pode ser ancestral da outra. Então, caso determine que são pessoas da mesma família, você pode reverter para o seu algoritmo, já que a árvore já não estará tão grande.

A página na [Wikipedia sobre Disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) pode te ajudar a achar uma solução para seu caso.